# How To Make This Responsive

Tags: html, responsive

I want to make this responsive. Every time I resize my window everything breaks.

```css
.first-about {
  margin-left: 220px;
}

.home-about1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.home-about1 .fa {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #ff4000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px white;
  color: white;
}

.hireus-text {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #31708f;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700px;
}

.hireus-text1 {
  background-color: #31708f;
  margin-left: 110px;
}

.hireus-text2 {
  background-color: #a73641;
}

.hireus-text3 {
  background-color: #298067;
}

.hireus-text4 {
  background-color: #8a5d0f;
}

.hireus-summary1 {
  background-color: #31708f;
  margin-left: 110px;
}

.hireus-summary2 {
  background-color: #a73641;
}

.hireus-summary3 {
  background-color: #298067;
}

.hireus-summary4 {
  background-color: #8a5d0f;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-about1">
  <div><i class="fa fa-users first-about" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: -10px;">
    </i></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="hireus-text1 hireus-text">
    <h2>FRIENDLY SUPPORT</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-text2 hireus-text">
    <h2>DETAILED REPORTING</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-text3 hireus-text">
    <h2>VERIFIED RESULTS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-text4 hireus-text">
    <h2>COMPETITIVE PRICE</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="hireus-summary1 hireus-summary">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis varius mi sit amet odio porta, at tincidunt mi auctor. Phasellus sed dolor eu mauris convallis interdum. Quisque mattis tincidunt lectus ut convallis. Integer quis metus a dui tristique
      posuere. Nulla ex ex, posuere a gravida et, auctor ut erat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-summary2 hireus-summary">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis varius mi sit amet odio porta, at tincidunt mi auctor. Phasellus sed dolor eu mauris convallis interdum. Quisque mattis tincidunt lectus ut convallis. Integer quis metus a dui tristique
      posuere. Nulla ex ex, posuere a gravida et, auctor ut erat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-summary3 hireus-summary">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis varius mi sit amet odio porta, at tincidunt mi auctor. Phasellus sed dolor eu mauris convallis interdum. Quisque mattis tincidunt lectus ut convallis. Integer quis metus a dui tristique
      posuere. Nulla ex ex, posuere a gravida et, auctor ut erat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hireus-summary4 hireus-summary">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis varius mi sit amet odio porta, at tincidunt mi auctor. Phasellus sed dolor eu mauris convallis interdum. Quisque mattis tincidunt lectus ut convallis. Integer quis metus a dui tristique
      posuere. Nulla ex ex, posuere a gravida et, auctor ut erat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to add the CSS

Comment: So add the CSS  :)

Comment: Sorry =) new to this platform..

Comment: No worries, there are a lot of hair-splitters on this platform,, hence the minus from people instead of helping you

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sankar!

Comment: @Nebulosar actually, a downvote is very reasonable for a question such as this. It shows he hasnt' done any research or tried a solution himself...

Comment: Well, i can agree after taking a wider view, but often,, people get some negative enforcement on asking a question, it makes me kinda fearful for asking my own

Comment: I was trying this for weeks trying add some bootstrap gridsystem and replacing other codes in my file.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. Setting up a parent div with a relative positioning and creating another element under that div as an absolute. Looks like it is working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your elements widths are fixed (300px for your blocks). So you need to make it "changes" when the screen is smaller.

So you have 2 solutions :

- Use a framework (like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/))
- Use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

So, if you want your blocks to be responsive with media queries, you can just specify a width :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hireus-text {
        width: 150px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the screen width is below 992px *(~from 0px up to 991px)* your element "hireus-text" will have a width of 150px.

So my real answer is, if you want to do some responsive, you'll need to learn the different ways you can use to do it. If you use a framework like Bootstrap, you'll see that sometimes you'll need to use media queries too :) ! Good luck